# dart: how to catch TypeError during compilation

Tags: dart

Below code throws a runtime error.

`TypeError: Instance of 'FormatException': type 'FormatException' is not a subtype of type 'CustomException'`

Why `Test(e)` does not fail at compilation as type of e is `Exception` and expected is `CustomException`. How to enforce it so one cannot pass `Exception` there.

```
abstract class CustomException implements Exception {
  String get code;
}

class Test {
  final CustomException ex;
  Test(this.ex);
}

void main() {
  try {
    throw new FormatException();
  } on Exception catch (e) {
    final t = Test(e);
    print('message: $t');
  }
}
```

Comment: Disable implicit casts: https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options#enabling-additional-type-checks

Comment: @jamesdlin that's great and seems working. Got lot of implicit casting error and will test out refactoring all.  Please also make it an answer so I can accept. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Dart has (for now) implicit downcasts from a supertype to a subtype. You are allowed to use an expression which is a super-type of the actual type that is required, under the assumption that you know what you are doing.

Here you have a value with static type `Exception` (the `e` that was caught), and you pass it to a constructor requiring a `CustomException`, which is a subtype of `Exception`.
The language allows this, but inserts a run-time downcast (equivalent to `e as CustomException`). That cast fails because the value is actually a `FormatException`.

With the up-coming null safety feature, implicit downcasts will be removed except from `dynamic` (because `dynamic` turns off static type checks anyway). When that happens, the `Test(e)` invocation becomes invalid. Until then, this code compilers and fails at run-time.

Until then, you can get the analyzer to warn you about implicit calls by configuring it in the [`analysis_options.yaml`](https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options#the-analysis-options-file) file